# PZL M28 Skytruck exhaust alignment

Tags: aircraft-design, feature-identification

Watching a short documentary on [PZL M28 Skytruck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PZL_M28_Skytruck), I noticed it has quite oddly aligned exhaust pipes.

They point almost directly downwards, with only slight aft tilt:

[image]
Picture credit: Łukasz Golowanow & Maciek Hypś, Konflikty.pl

Does anyone have factual information as to why the exhaust is directed such?

Common sense would suggest it is done to keep hot exhaust from hitting the flaps and the wing strut. But when considering the common usage of M28 from unpaved  runways, such exhaust alignment seems odd as it most certainly will kick up all kinds of debris.

Comment: I think the flow of exhaust is not significant enough to kick up any debris. It's more likely to avoid blasting the strut with heat and paint discolouration from the exhaust residue. I don't have any facts to back this up so I will refrain from answering.

Comment: I stepped into the same trap at first @MichaelHall , after the documentary I browsed the web, not yet knowing M28 is a develpoment of An-28. An-28 has the exhaust at the back of the nacelle, so this must be what you had in mind. M28 uses PT6A engines, hence the different exhaust arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a deicing cuff of some sort on the leading edge of the wing; it may be that the exhaust is angled down to avoid frying the cuff.

Comment: There would be no point deicing such a small area. I think it may be a cuff to protect the strut from hot exhaust.